# mysql triggers to group data and sum the data

Tags: mysql, datetime

i have an input table called as meter1 and i want sql query in triggers.

```
datetime          energy   vrms   irms
2014/11/10 04:00  10       230    100
2014/11/10 04:59  20       230    100
2014/12/10 05:00  30       230    100
2014/12/10 05:59  40       230    100
```

my output should be like this and stored in hourly table

```
 datetime                  energy  total(vrms*irms)   vmax  imax 
 2014/11/10 04:00-04:59       30      23000             230   100
 2014/12/10 05:00-05:59       70      23000             230   100
```

here i want to group data based on every 1 hour,date,and month and i want to calculate vmax,imax, sum of energy,and total. I want mysql trigger qyery.

```
my sql query
INSERT INTO hourly
SELECT CONCAT( HOUR(duration), ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(duration), ':59:59' ) ) AS time_frame,
sum(energy) AS energy,max(vrms) AS vmax,max(irms) AS imax,(vrms*irms) AS total                  
FROM meter21 
GROUP BY DATE(duration), HOUR(duration)
```

please any one help me out to write the query in triggers.
any one help me out  ......

Comment: Okay, have a try then. Write the sql statement first and have a try in using it in a trigger afterwards. If you have a question about any of these steps, feel free to ask.

Comment: @fancyPants i had tried in sql.. it worked. but i don't know how to do in triggers..help me out.

Comment: We don't write a whole tutorial for every question asked. Name your problem exactly, show what you've tried.

Comment: Why do you need a trigger for this?

Comment: @Rahul  i will be getting data for few minutes and data gets interupted for some seconds.. so  i need triggers ...any other way please tell me if possible

Comment: @fancyPants i have written the sql query . i want the query with help of triggers.